# Mscgen / trace2uml input file generator from source code

Tags: input, parser-generator

is there a way to generate Mscgen / trace2uml compatible input files (description files/text) from source code, to be able to later generate the sequence diagrams? The project homepages mention Message Sequence Chart descriptions that no program seem to generate. I would hate to go over the entire code and create the sequence descriptors myself. Other tools that would let me generate sequence diagrams from source code would help too..

Answer (score 1):

"generating sequence charts from source code" is not possible. Because a state chart is not a statically view to the program, but a view to an example of a program RUN.

But you can "trace" a program, while it is running, and use the trace output for the diagram. Thats the reason, why Trace2UML is called "trace to uml" ;-)

All you need is a trace framework (class) that does the correct trace formate.
A good one is "Trace2UML.cpp" you can find in the Astade distribution.

e.g.: http://daily.astade.de/2011-08-25/astade-1.1.4-dev-2375.tar.gz